# Можно ли вывести время компиляции программы в NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, компиляция, компилятор

Хотелось бы сравнить время компиляции двух программ, дабы определить, какая из них компилируется быстрее.

Comment: Не особо обращал на это внимание, но кажется netbeans пишет типа такого compilation complete in 120 secund в выводе лога компиляции